# retrieving data from API using JQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, openweathermap

[image]

I am trying to get the information from openweathermap api into my app. I tried using ajax to get the data, but it is shown as undefined.

```
   $(function(){

        var $temp = $('#temperature');
        var $humidity = $('#humidity')
        temp = document.getElementById("temperature");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={' +
                  markers["title"] + '}&APPID=' + APPID,
            success: function(data){
              console.log('success', data);
              $temp.append(data.main.temp);
              $humidity.append(data.main.humidity);
            }

        });

      });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + markers["title"] + '</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<div class = "temperature"><span id = "temperature"> '+ temp +' </span>&degC</div>' +
      '<div class = "humidity">'+ humidity +'<span id = "humidity"></span>%' +
      '</div>';`
```

Comment: what is `markers['title']`

Comment: yes, please, provide the exemple we can try to use.

Comment: Are you sure that URL is formed properly? Have you checked the console output for errors?

Comment: He can't give his key, but here I got a working link from the Documentation: http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1

Comment: If there is a problemm with URL he just gonna have ajax error, but if he got "undefined", probably, he just parse answer in a wrong way. DYC, could you please show what exactly you got in "data" response?

Comment: @wilsonhobbs Hi, in this app, I am combining both openweathermap and google map api. markers["title"] is the result from search box by the user. The data from openweathermap are meant to be shown in an InfoWindows (that uses the content string) locating at the place that was searched. The url works fine because all the data are shown in the console.log. Would you like me to post all the codes?

Comment: @TimurGilauri ^

Comment: @Difster yes, the url works fine as the console.log shows all the data from the API

Comment: this is an example of the API http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={KL}&APPID=e9e239c6585f081bee7b0d7f6045a53f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to JSON.parse() your data. $ajax is likely returning a string, so you need to parse the data before you can get properties out of it.

The reason you are getting an undefined error is because  you can't retrieve properties of a string.

Comment: Hi, when I tried using getJSON instead, I am able to load the data I want and show it on console.log. However, the info in InfoWindow are still shown as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

By geographic coordinates :

```
        var apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&units=imperial&cnt=7&appid=" + APIkey;
```

Use the geolocation to provide values for latitude and longitude.

or simply provide City Id's

```
var apiUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=' + APIkey;
```